# Why do I get ArgumentError when using abstract base model with SQLAlchemyAutoSchema?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I extended the Flask SQLAlchemy base model as below to create my own custom base model.
Why do I get the following error from the below code?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression expected for argument 'remote_side'; got <built-in function id>.
```

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

*Update*: Apologies for cutting down the context too much.  It's a large model hierarchy and I was misled because the line referenced in the error stack trace below was:

```
  File ".../models.py", line 588, in <module>
    class CountrySchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
```

Perhaps this is because CountrySchema is the first schema in the file?
The real problem seems to be with the foreign key to same table in Transaction which was working until I moved the id field into the BaseModel.
How do I change the split_from_tx_id and/or split_from_tx definitions to get it working again?

Also, FYI, the SQLAlchemy related versions from my Pipfile are:

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy = "==3.0.5"
marshmallow-sqlalchemy = "==0.29.0"
SQLAlchemy = "==1.4.49"
```

Error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../models.py", line 588, in <module>
    class CountrySchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 116, in __new__
    klass._declared_fields = mcs.get_declared_fields(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 91, in get_declared_fields
    fields.update(mcs.get_declared_sqla_fields(fields, converter, opts, dict_cls))
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 130, in get_declared_sqla_fields
    converter.fields_for_model(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 136, in fields_for_model
    for prop in model.__mapper__.attrs:
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1184, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2505, in attrs
    self._check_configure()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1941, in _check_configure
    _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3527, in _configure_registries
    _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3566, in _do_configure_registries
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1958, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 231, in init
    self.do_init()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2150, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2238, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.remote_side = util.column_set(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2239, in <genexpr>
    coercions.expect(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 193, in expect
    resolved = impl._literal_coercion(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 378, in _literal_coercion
    self._raise_for_expected(element, argname)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 290, in _raise_for_expected
    util.raise_(exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code), replace_context=err)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression expected for argument 'remote_side'; got <built-in function id>.
```

Trimmed models.py:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    __table_args__ = {"mysql_engine": "InnoDB"}
    __mapper_args__ = {"always_refresh": True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    last_changed_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)

@declarative_mixin
class UserIdMixin():
    @declared_attr
    def user_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    @classmethod
    def get_by_user_id(cls, user_id):
        items = cls.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
        if not items:
            return []
        return items

class Country(BaseModel):
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    code = db.Column(db.String(2), unique=True, nullable=False)
    is_available = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

class Address(BaseModel):
    postal_code = db.Column(db.String(80))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("country.id"), nullable=False)

class Transaction(BaseModel, UserIdMixin):
    is_split = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    split_from_tx_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('transaction.id'))
    split_from_tx = db.relationship('Transaction', remote_side=[id], backref='splitters')

class Contact(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True
    email_address = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    @declared_attr
    def address_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.id'))

class Person(Contact):
    __abstract__ = True
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

class User(Person):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    last_login = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    # other fields including some like below
    #language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("language.id"))
    #goal_settings_id = db.relationship("GoalSettings", uselist=False)
    #notifications = db.relationship("UserNotification")

    def update_last_login(self):
        self.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
            return {
              "success": False,
              "message": str(e)
            }, 422

class CountrySchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        load_instance = True

class AddressSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True

class TransactionSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True

class UserSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = (['password_hash'])
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True
        include_relationships = True
```